Generate OWL from RDF generated data
I have simple relational database tables
drugs (drug_id(PK), traditional_name, category, factory_id(FK) ....)
chemical composition (Id(PK), scientific_name, ... )
drugs_compositions (Id(pk), drug_id, compo_id) -- this is many-to-many relation table, links drugs with its compositions.
drug_factory (id(pk), factory_name, country, address ....)

I have used D2RQ to generate mapping,
then got Data with RDF format also by using D2RQ.
till now everything is good.

so can I generate OWL ontology based on RDF generated data ?
if it is not possible then what is the easiest way to create ontology compatible with existing RDF data?

I know the traditional way is creating OWL, then add data to it, but in my case I already have data (in DB) and want to generate RDF and OWL, is there any roadmap easier than my approach above?

the real goal is generating entailments on this data to get new facts like alternative drugs, drug contraindications. and ease link it with other existing biomedical ontologies, please help or suggest how to achieve this goal by using any tools for this (protege, Jena Fuseki, D2RQ, or other tools).



I don't see any non-hierarchical relationships in your sample RDBMS (just terminology trees). Also, what is a M:M table? Not sure that possible. 1:M and M:1 is customary but I've never seen a M:M implementation.
You might be better off (i.e. less effort) starting with a sample that is close to your objectives and then updating to capture your terms and relationships.

Ok, In fact drugs_compositions table is representing  many to many relation, what I ment is a short writing of what you wrote verbosly, I am with you about it. (every drug has multiple chemical  compositions, and every chemical composition is part of multiple medicens or drugs.), however, my questions about generating OWL based on existing data in RDF, or in other words, what is the best approach to build OWL ontology for already existing data?  thank you in advanced. @JayGray

From what I can see, which is very limited, you have the basis for building a list of items and their attributes. That's a start. But the real work is object properties (aka predicates {?p} or relationships among subject {?s} and object {?o}). At the end of the day, that represents ~80% of the effort, so you have a way to to go.
My previous advice: start with templates. See Ontobee and  OBO


you will still need some ontology aka schema in OWL. Then you can use any OBDA system of your choice, write a mapping and have access to the data as RDF.

